# non repeating random letters on table

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a table with non repeating random letters (uppercase only) using JavaScript.  Someone posted an answer, but it was deleted before I got a chance to ask: 1) Why is there a var x and a var y instead of having only a var x? 2)Why do you put i-1 in return letters[i-1]?

HTML5:

```
<table class="bingo">
    <tr>
        <td id="square0"></td>
        <td id="square1"></td>
        <td id="square2"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="square3"></td>
        <td id="square4"></td>
        <td id="square5"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="square6"></td>
        <td id="square7"></td>
        <td id="square8"></td>
   </tr>
 </table>
```

JS

```
//Create capital letters A - Z array
var letters = [];
    for (var i = 65; i < 91; i++) {
      letters.push(String.fromCharCode(i));
}

//Confuse about why there is a var x and a var y?
    for (var i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
       var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 26);
       var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 26);
       var temp = letters[x];
       letters[x] = letters[y];
       letters[y] = temp;
 }

 var rLetter = function(i) {
  return letters[i-1];
};

window.onload = function () {
  //calls the function  
  $("square0").innerHTML = rLetter(1);
  $("square1").innerHTML = rLetter(2);
  $("square2").innerHTML = rLetter(3);
  $("square3").innerHTML = rLetter(4);
  $("square4").innerHTML = rLetter(5);
  $("square5").innerHTML = rLetter(6);
  $("square6").innerHTML = rLetter(7);
  $("square7").innerHTML = rLetter(8);
  $("square8").innerHTML = rLetter(9);
```

}

Comment: You need the X and Y because it's [randomizing](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2450976/502613) the array of letters. Re-using variables is bad practice. You don't really need `i - 1` but it'll let you start at `1` in the `onload` function instead of `0`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var letters = [];
for (var i = 65; i < 91; i++) {
  letters.push(String.fromCharCode(i));
}
```

The code above is creating an array with characters from A to Z in **alphabetical, non-random order**.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
  var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 26);
  var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 26);
  var temp = letters[x];
  letters[x] = letters[y];
  letters[y] = temp;
}
```

Answering your first question, what this code is doing is creating two random numbers (`x` and `y`) and a variable named `temp` to hold the contents of `letters[x]`. Then, the function assigns `letters[x]` to be whatever `letters[y]` was, then assigning `letters[x]` to be whatever `letters[y]` was. **The point of this** is to make the `letters` array randomized.

Let's say that `x = 1` and `y = 2`:

```
var temp = 'B';     // because letters[1] = B
letters[1] = 'C';   // because letters[2] = C
letters[2] = 'B';   // because temp = B
```

So now, the `letters` array looks like:

```
letters[0] = A
letters[1] = C
letters[2] = B
// etc...
```

It's basically just *randomizing* the entire array.

Lastly, answering your second question, the reason you put `[i-1]` is because the `letters` array index starts at 0. So when you call `rLEtters(1)`, it is actually grabbing 0 (1-1 = 0) from the `letters` array.

Comment: Unfortunately, the result of this isn't actually random - it's biased.  Jeff Atwood has written an exellent [blog post](http://blog.codinghorror.com/the-danger-of-naivete/) explaining why.

Comment: @WesFoster Thank you for the explanation.  Trying to understand your example, a little confuse about the B,C,B  <br/>
    var temp = letters[x];  <br/>
    letters[x] = letters[y];  <br/>
 letters[y] = temp;  <br/>
so x = 1, y = 2  <br/>
var temp = letter[1];     // because letters[1] = B   <br/>
letters[1] = letter[2]';   // because letters[2] = C   <br/>
letters[2] = letter[1];   // because temp = B   <br/>

Comment: @user5117220 Has this helped you?

Answer (score 0):

> 1) Why is there a var x and a var y instead of having only a var x?

It looks like this code creates an array of all capital letters, then "randomizes" them by switching the location of 2 letters 26 times. 2 variables need to be created to hold the position of each of the 2 letters that are being switched.

> 2)Why do you put i-1 in return letters[i-1]?

The array is zero-indexed meaning the first value in the array is at letters[0]. Using i-1 allows you to get the 1st value in the array by using rLetter(1), rather than getting the 2nd value.

I would have personally done it like this:

```
var usedLetters = [];

var rLetter = function(i) {
  var alreadyUsed = 0;
  var letter;
  while(alreadyUsed >= 0) {
    var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 26);
    letter = String.fromCharCode(65 + x);
    alreadyUsed = usedLetters.indexOf(letter);
  }
  usedLetters.push(letter);
  return letter;
};


window.onload = function () {
  //calls the function  
  $("square0").innerHTML = rLetter(1);
  $("square1").innerHTML = rLetter(2);
  $("square2").innerHTML = rLetter(3);
  $("square3").innerHTML = rLetter(4);
  $("square4").innerHTML = rLetter(5);
  $("square5").innerHTML = rLetter(6);
  $("square6").innerHTML = rLetter(7);
  $("square7").innerHTML = rLetter(8);
  $("square8").innerHTML = rLetter(9);
```

}

Sorry for any code errors. I have very little experience in JS.

Comment: Thank you, I will try that.

Answer (score 0):

If you actually want a random shuffle (at least algorithmically), you can't just do 26 random swaps of letters (as another answer did).

The result of that is biased - see [Implementation errors in Fisher-Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle#Implementation_errors) & also [Jeff Atwood's post on naïveté](http://blog.codinghorror.com/the-danger-of-naivete/).

Below, I've used Mike Bostock's implementation of the Fisher-Yates shuffle to produce an unbiased random ordering of letters (up to the limits of javascript's random number generator anyway).

```
//  create array of uppercase letters
var letters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'.split('');

// implentation of the Fischer-Yeates shuffle
// as written by Mike Bostock (http://bost.ocks.org/mike/shuffle/)
function shuffle(array) {
  var m = array.length, t, i;

  // While there remain elements to shuffle…
  while (m) {

    // Pick a remaining element…
    i = Math.floor(Math.random() * m--);

    // And swap it with the current element.
    t = array[m];
    array[m] = array[i];
    array[i] = t;
  }

  return array;
}

window.onload = function () {

    var shuffled = shuffle(letters);

    for (var i=0; i<9; i++) {
        $("#square" + i).html(shuffled[i]);
    }

}
```

[Codepen here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EjJYeW).